# Как правильно расположить {% for i in iterable%} ... {% endif %} в шаблоне DJANGO3.0?

Tags: python, django

**Задача**: на странице рендерятся записи из БД, рядом с каждой кнопка модального окна, в котором должны быть Подробности из бд по соответствующей записи.
схематически так:

```
{% for item in work_exp %}
...html код..
{{ item.description }}
...html код..
{% endfor %}
```

То есть это одна Модель, которая *разбирается* и на страницу и на модальные окна.

**Проблема:**
Записи рендерятся корректно, а в модальных окнах у всех записей отображаются Подробности первой, хотя весь блок выполняется в одном цикле **for**.
как правильно расставить цикл?

Полный код далее...

**base.html**

```
...
<div class="container">
#НАЧАЛО ЦИКЛА
      {% for item in work_exp %}
      <tr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
            <h4 class="post-title">
# РЕНДЕР ЗАПИСИ
              {{ item.position }} - "{{ item.company_name }}"
            </h4>
            <p class="post-meta">Период работы: с
                    {{ item.start_date }}
                  {% if item.end_date %}
                    по {{ item.end_date }}
                  {% else %}
                    по настоящее время
                  {% endif %}
          </a>
              <!-- Button trigger modal -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                  Подробнее
              </button>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ job.position }}</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
# РЕНДЕР ПОДРОБНОСТЕЙ В МОДАЛЬНОМ ОКНЕ
                              <p>{{ item.company_name }}</p>
                              <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
                <hr>
          </div>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**models.py**

```
class WorkingExperience(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Место работы')
    position = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Должность')
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Начало работы')
    end_date = models.DateField(
            verbose_name='Окончание работы',
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            help_text='Оставьте поле пустым чтобы получить значение "По настоящее время"',
        )
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание обязанностей')
    company_web_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Сайт компании', null=True, blank=True)
```

**SELECT из БД на всякий**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**views.py**

```
class BaseView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        work_exp = WorkingExperience.objects.all()
        context = {'work_exp': work_exp}
        return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

А в результате во всех модалках Подробности первой записи...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: P.S. Если кто-то кроме ответа сможет подсказать годную и внятную статью/пособие по Джанго шаблонам, будет отдельная благодарность)

Comment: я думаю проблема в том, что у тебя у всех окон генерируется один и тот же id и потом когда ты открываешь окно открывается первое окно с таким id. добавь `id="exampleModal{{forloop.counter}}"`

Comment: @Andrey Maslov Ну ты просто герой! помогло! Спасибо вселенское! Собственно я сам об этом подумывал, в моем комментарии ниже, но я бы очень долго страдал))) Сейчас начал читать Дронова, надеюсь там это раскрывается